# Finding all usages of a filename string in other files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, search

I have a directory of images (e.g. image1.png). However the images could be within directories within directories (recursive).

I would like to go through this image directory, grab the filename, and search for all usages in another directory (recursive as well). If there are no usages, I would like to mark it. In essence I would like to fnd out what images are not used in any files (php/html/css/etc).

I have seen some hints to use first

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

followed by

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

But my linux command skills are struggling to figure a script out for this.
Has anyone done this before?

Sample data:
Directory:

```
.
├── aboutus
│   └── logos
│       ├── us.jpg
```

Example usage:

```
background-image: image-url('images/aboutus/logo/us.jpg');
```

Comment: Why is this posted tagged "php"? Seems to be a shell problem.

Comment: give examples of how the images are referenced in the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop like this to get a list of images not found:

```
cd /base/dir/to/check/presence/of/image/files

while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do
   img="${f##*/}" # get the filename
   grep -qFr "$img" --include=*.html --include=*.php --include=*.css . ||
      echo "$img not found"
done < <(find /img-dir -type f -print0) > imgNotFound.txt
```

Comment: kind of works i see. But could I search just by the filename and not the path? e.g. instead of ./aboutus/logos/test.png it should be test.png?

Comment: Check updated answer now to work with just the base filename.

Comment: hmm i need to specify the directory where the images are and also specify where the directory for the htm/css/php is as they are on different levels

Comment: Yes in first `cd` specify the full path to base directory of `htm/css/php` and replace `/img-dir` by full path of the the directory where the images are.